# SQL create a report providing details and summary row for each group with distinct count

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

#### Table1:

**company_id**   **customer_id**   **customer_name** 
  1                        100                  Johnson
  1                        200                  Jones
  3                        300                  Smith

#### Table2:

**company_id**   **company_name**
  1                      Alpha
  1                      Delta

I want to obtain a summary report with a result that will produce the following:

#### Result Table:

**company_name**   **customer_id**   **customer_name** 
  Alpha                       100                  Johnson
                                  200                  Jones
  *Total:  2*
  Delta                       300                  Smith
  *Total:  1*

I have seen some sample using a sum aggregate but that errors out because I am not totaling a column.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Consider doing this in Application side with help of two queries. One to pull customer details and one to count

Comment: Crystal reports could easily do what you are asking.

Comment: @dcreight - Crystal would be easy; however, I am doing this in a java portlet and am createing a prepared statement to get the data.

Comment: SSRS would be you're best bet then.  You can integrate with java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server can't output the result you've asked for in a single query; with multiple results sets, formatting and repeated values missing it's really not the sort of thing it can do. I can write TSQL that'll get close to it, but you'll need to use cursors and the results will still be something that'll need specific application support to display to your end users.

You're best off for this sort of thing (IMHO) looking at tools such as SSRS or Crystal Reports, where it should be fairly straightforwards.